# How do I get a large number of records from Firebase via the web API?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I've got the following code running on an Express node js server:

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var ref = new Firebase(config.firebaseURL);
ref.auth(config.firebaseAuth);

var employeeProfiles=ref.child('employeeProfiles');
employeeProfiles.on('child_added', addOrUpdateEmployeeProfile);
employeeProfiles.on('child_changed', addOrUpdateEmployeeProfile);
```

When this code is initially run the ,on() should get called for every node at that  ref, however it stops about 4000 objects in...leaving me with only 20% of the data.

How do I enumerate a large number of records?

Comment: You're not using any [limit queries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries), right?

Comment: Could be something in your `addOrUpdateEmployeeProfile` method

Comment: No... is there a hard limit on how many nodes I can receive callbacks for?

Comment: callback currently just logs to the console so I doubt that...

Comment: Other limitations are at the bottom of [this page](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html). The read limit seems to be 100 million o.o

Comment: If all children already exists when you attach the listener, the data should normally be sent from server to client in one "frame". Can you check what you get when you enable logging: `Firebase.enableLogging(true)`?

Comment: It seems to at least log (via Firebase.enableLogging(true)) in batches.  Is .on() supposed to be reliable?

Comment: Turns out it was my co generator wrapper getting an error from another api I was calling that dropped some of my expected objects.